# Numbers distribution

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a problem with numbers distribution to perfectly fit given container. My numbers are:

```
int[] number = {50, 40, 30, 30, 25, 25};
```

I want to find a best combo which will be nearest to 100, and when no more options available start another container of 100. Simple solution like sorting and adding from max to min won't work, because:

```
int[] firstContainer = { 50, 40 };         //10 unused
int[] secontContainer = { 30, 30, 25 };    //15 unused
int[] thirdContainer = { 25 };             //75 unused
```

The result what I'm looking for is:

```
int[] firstContainer = { 50, 25, 25 };     //0 unused
int[] secontContainer = { 40, 30, 30 };    //0 unused
```

Is there any kind soul willing to help me solve the problem?

Comment: Is the sum of original array guaranteed to be multiple of 100?

Comment: No, it's not, sum may, and mostly will differ from multiple of 100

Comment: Then your criteria of the desired result is underspecified. What if there are no combinations summing up to 100, how will you define the best fit?

Comment: As I mentioned - nearest to 100 from all possible combinations. In addition, none of elements will be greater than 100

Comment: So what is What is better, two sums 98, 98 or 97, 99? Like if you have an original array of [1, 97, 98].

Comment: 99, 97 would be best

Comment: Then this is what needs to be specified. Would it be correct to say you want to find the sum closest to 100 first, exclude it's elements, then repeat on the remaining elements?

Comment: That's exactly what I need. I just didnt know how to form it this way :)

Comment: Then the only think remaining is to have an algorithm finding a combination of elements closest to 100. That's a known problem and you find different solutions to it ([example](https://rafal.io/posts/k-numbers-sum-to-c.html)). If the algorithm is failing you fall back to 99. Then 98, until found. Then repeat for the rest of elements. This is a naive algorithm, but will do what you need.

Comment: Please post the code you have that's not working correctly so we can help you fix it.

Comment: The "bin packing problem" is a research level problem. Beyond brute force and simple randomized solution, you're not going to get the optimal solution on a Q&A site such as Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a universal problem called then "bin packing problem".  It is np-awful, even the 1-dimensional problem.  Standard application is cutting planks from 100 feet stock.  Google "c# bin packing" for solutions, lotsa hits.

Comment: Hah, you two great minds think alike apparently. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution - it can be optimized and improved, but now you have a starting point. Starting point is to create all combinations of your initial array and then get the sum

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] number = { 50, 40, 30, 30, 25, 25 };

    foreach (var kvp in Exercise(number, 100))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Solution " + kvp.Key);
        foreach (var sol in kvp.Value)
        {
            Console.Write(sol + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

private static Dictionary<int, List<int>> Exercise(int[] number, int sum)
{
    Dictionary<int, List<int>> results = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
    int counter = 0;

    var numberOfCombinations = Math.Pow(2, number.Count());
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCombinations; i++)
    {
        //convert an int to binary and pad it with 0, so I will get an array which is the same size of the input[] array. ie for example 00000, then 00001, .... 11111 
        var temp = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(number.Count(), '0').ToArray();
        List<int> positions = new List<int>();
        int total = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < temp.Length; k++)
        {
            if (temp[k] == '1')
            {
                total += number[k];
                positions.Add(number[k]);
            }
        }

        if (total == sum)
        {
            results.Add(counter, positions);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Hi @RufusL I added a comment, hopefully is better now. Temp is used as a mask to flag the inputs to be used in the calculation

Comment: Up-voted as clever solution using  a binary map to obtain the all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on generating random and feasible answers, at the end we can find best answer :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] number = { 50, 40, 30, 30, 25, 25 };
        int bound = 100;
        var numbers = new List<dynamic>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var ans_collection = new List<List<List<int>>>();
        //number of random answers , best answer depends on i so you can't be sure this algorithm always finds optimal answer choose i big enough...
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < number.Length; j++)
            {
                numbers.Add(new { num = number[j], seen = false });
            }
            var ans = new List<List<int>>();
            var container = new List<int>();
            var distSum = 0;
            //while loop generates a distribution
            while (numbers.Where(x => !x.seen).Count() > 0)
            {
                var chosen = numbers.OrderBy(x => rnd.NextDouble()).Where(x => !x.seen && distSum + x.num <= bound).FirstOrDefault();
                if (numbers.Where(x => !x.seen && distSum + x.num <= bound).Count() > 0)
                {
                    container.Add(chosen.num);
                    distSum += chosen.num;
                    numbers.Add(new { num = chosen.num, seen = true });
                    numbers.Remove(chosen);
                    if (numbers.Where(x => !x.seen && distSum + x.num <= bound).Count() == 0)
                    {
                        ans.Add(new List<int>(container));
                        container = new List<int>();
                        distSum = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ans.Add(new List<int>(container));
                    container = new List<int>();
                    distSum = 0;
                }
            }
            ans_collection.Add(new List<List<int>>(ans));
        }


        //find best answer based on sum of *unused* amounts
        var min = ans_collection.Min(ans => ans.Sum(dis => (bound - dis.Sum())));
        var best = ans_collection.Where(ans => ans.Sum(dis => (bound - dis.Sum())) == min).FirstOrDefault();

        best.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", x.Select(Y => Y.ToString()))));
    }
```